# discord.js: TypeError: Cannot read property 'memberCount' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get the number count of my discord server, I thought this would work, but I get an error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'memberCount' of undefined"

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("739242587076034620");

const memberCount = guild.memberCount;
console.log(memberCount)
```

I looked everywhere and couldn't find a solution, people say that the guild id is wrong but I'm basically 100% sure it's right.

Comment: There could be a possiblity that server is wrong , if the server is really correct then enable widget mode from the server settings and put in this link https://img.shields.io/discord/739242587076034620?style=for-the-badge check if it returns a embed which will say how many are online that will give you a confirmation if its right or wrong.

Comment: can you log `guild`.

Comment: I found a solution and it was just that i needed to do ` const guild = await client.guilds.cache.get("739242587076034620");` and put it in an async function

Answer (score 0):

`guild.memberCount` is not a function.

You are looking for `guild.size`

I also checked whether the id for the server exists, and it does.
Please note however that since you are using cache, it is highly unlikely that the member count will be exactly accurate - there is no easy fix to this problem.

Comment: guild.memberCount worked for me, I just needed to do ` const guild = await client.guilds.cache.get("739242587076034620");` and put it in an async function

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem like 2 months ago and the problem is that the cache doesn't have all the members inside(as it seems for you not even one).I remember vaguely that it had to do with the bot permissions(it would only load like 3 members me,the bot and the admin),you could tinker with them in the developer portal and use the intent constructor to give the appropriate permissions.Then the memberCount property will work properly

Comment: I found a solution and it was just that i needed to do ` const guild = await client.guilds.cache.get("739242587076034620");` and put it in an async function

Comment: I wasn't even aware of this option,since i somehow made it work without await but that is way less effort,nice one!